# Removing HTML from a string

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, encoding

I have a table (a Wijmo Grid). The column Log takes some text.

The user is allowed to write `HTML` in the text, because the same text is also used when mailed to make it look pretty and well styled.

Let's say the text is:

```
var text = "Hello friend <br> How are you? <h1> from me </h1>";
```

Is there any method or JSON.stringify() og HTML.enocde() i can/should use to get:

```
var textWithoutHtml = magic(text); // "Hello friend How are you? from me"
```

One of the problems is that if the text include `"<br>"` it break to next line i the row of the table, and it's possible to see the top-half of the second line in the row, witch doesn't look good.

Comment: you have to encode it using C# or javaScript?

Comment: please have a loo at this http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

Comment: @Sid M I think I have the options of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = "Hello friend <br> How are you? <h1> from me </h1>";
var newText = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfRs6/

Comment: Could you short describe what the Regex does? I can't write Regex.

Comment: So it removes all tags (<...>) in the text?

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("Hello friend <br> How are you? <h1> from me </h1>", @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
```

You can also check the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

```
<[^>]+>|&nbsp;/
1st Alternative: <[^>]+>
< matches the characters < literally
[^>]+ match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
> a single character in the list > literally (case sensitive)
> matches the characters > literally
2nd Alternative: &nbsp;
&nbsp; matches the characters &nbsp; literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Could you short describe what the Regex does? I can't write Regex.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood your question you can encode the values like this in C#

```
string encodedValue= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtInput.Text);
```

**Note:** here txtInput is the id of TextBox on your page.

Comment: This is a good solution too, if you don't want the tags to be removed but displayed as plain text.

Comment: @radbyx : yeah indeed it is.. :)